# Are string numeric literals with floating point suffix the valid CLI arguments in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

The Ballerina specification on `fromString()` methods of langlibs `float` and `decimal`  says that the FloatingPointTypeSuffix is not allowed. Should this be considered for CLI args also?

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main(decimal d) {
    io:println(d);
}
```

For example, is `"12.53d"` a valid CLI argument to pass here?

Answer (score 0):

`is "12.53d" a valid CLI argument to pass here?`, No, FloatingPointTypeSuffix is not allowed.

This is because we have to use the same `fromString()` function to convert CLI arguments internally.